# SQL update keeps spitting syntax errors when my code seems properly formatted

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I have this piece of code that tries to update the `date` column with `ID` = `m`. `m` is an integer as it's supposed to be and for `date` I have tried both a `string` and a `datetime.date`.

```sql
  sql = '''UPDATE DaByDay
           SET Date = ?
           WHERE ID = ?'''
  crsr.execute(sql, date, m)
  cnxn.commit()
```

Yet I keep getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\database test.py", line 47, in 
> crsr.execute(sql, date, m)
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement. (-3503) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Now how should I go about solving this?

Comment: Should avoid using reserved words as names. Date is a reserved word in Access. Perhaps enclose field name in brackets `[Date]`. Probably unrelated to issue but could use a quote mark instead of triple apostrophe.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, do you wish to post it as an answer so I can mark it and have it be more visibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should avoid using reserved words as names. Date is a reserved word in Access. Enclose field name in brackets `[Date]`.

In addition, if name uses space or special characters also enclose in brackets.

Probably unrelated to issue but could use a quote mark instead of triple apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the proper syntax for date literals is 'YYYY-MM-DD' (within quotes) or #mm/dd/yyyy# (within hash marks) you should try supplying in that manner. Also Date is a reserved word in Access you should use square brackets around it.